# Выразите в рекурсивной функции следующее (гибрид факториала и арифметической прогрессии):

Tags: c++, рекурсия

```
int n = 10;
int x = 1;
int y = 0;  
for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    x = x * i;
    y = y + x;
}

cout << y;
```

Возможно ли выразить это рекурсивно?

Comment: Возможно. Циклы и рекурсия взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void func(int &x, int &y, int idx) {
  if (idx > 1) {
    func(x, y, idx - 1);
    x *= idx;
  }
  y += x;
}

int n = 10;
int x = 1;
int y = 0;
func(x, y, n)  
cout << y;
```

Comment: Круто, буду стремиться решать такие задачки так-же быстро